# Zend email debug

Tags: debugging, zend-framework, email

I am trying to find an equivalent way to debug an email in Zend like I can in cakePHP.  I want to see my test output before I send an email out for testing.  I could just send the email to myself, and work bugs out that way, but I find that tedious.

```
//zend mail
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyHTML($content);
$mail->setBodyText($content);
$mail->setFrom('noreply@joe.com', 'Security Notification');
$mail->addTo('joeschmo@joe.com');
$mail->setSubject('(Security Notify) New Security Request');
//$mail->send();

//Equivalent to this from cakePHP
$this->Email->delivery = 'debug'; 
$this->Email->send('test message'); 
debug($this->Session->read('Message.email'));
die();
```

Comment: something like: die($mail->getBodyHtml()) or die(print_r($mail))

Comment: @DirkMcQuickly can you please post this as an answer so I can accept this as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like:

```
die($mail->getBodyHtml());
```

or

```
die(print_r($mail));
```

Answer (score 0):

For your content in HTML, you can simply write:

```
echo $content; exit();
```

And for your content in plain text write:

```
echo '<pre>' . $content . '</pre>'; exit();
```